# What is the proper way to output the result of a math function on a data property within a v-for loop in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, interpolation, v-for

I've been working on a dice roller in Vue as part of a game. I loop through the types of dice with v-for to create a set of buttons and an affiliated div that will display the result. The issue is that even though my console logs are correct, I can't seem to get my rollResult to update where it should be interpolated. I've included only the necessary code to save all of your eyes. If I can provide anymore, please let me know. Thank you in advance!

HTML:

```
<v-list-tile v-for="die in dice" :key="die.name">
...
 <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
      <v-btn class="primary" @click="rollDice(die.sides)">Roll</v-btn> 
          <div>{{rollResult}}</div>
</template>
...
</v-list-tile>
```

Data:

```
      rollResult: 0,
      dice: [
        { sides: 4 },
        { sides: 6 },
        { sides: 8 },
        { sides: 10 },
        { sides: 12 },
        { sides: 20 }
      ],
```

Function:

```
    rollDice: function(n) {
     let rollResult = Math.ceil(Math.random() * n);
        console.log(rollResult);
    }
```

Comment: Your `rollDice` method doesn't update any component data. `rollResult` is a local variable which is not accessible outside of that method. Did you mean to assign to `this.rollResult` instead?

Comment: Doh! I definitely did, though! now that I have done so, the issue remains. :( edit: typo

Comment: you mean `this.rollResult = Math.ceil(Math.random() * n);`

Comment: Awesome! That worked! Though now they all seem to be bound to the same value. This has me super excited!

Comment: it's not working because you assigning your value to local variable with `let` keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a local variable, not mutating the state (the `data`). Use:

```js
rollDice: function(n) {
    this.rollResult = Math.ceil(Math.random() * n);
    console.log(this.rollResult);
}
```

Demo:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!',
    rollResult: 0,
    dice: [
      { sides: 4 },
      { sides: 6 },
      { sides: 8 },
      { sides: 10 },
      { sides: 12 },
      { sides: 20 }
    ],
  },
  methods: {
    rollDice: function(n) {
        this.rollResult = Math.ceil(Math.random() * n);
        console.log(this.rollResult);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="die in dice" :key="die.name">
    <button class="primary" @click="rollDice(die.sides)">Roll {{ die.sides }}</button>
    <div>{{rollResult}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you need invididual results, turn `rollResult` into an array (or an object) and watch out for some caveats (like using `Vue.set()`):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!',
    rollResult: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    dice: [
      { sides: 4 },
      { sides: 6 },
      { sides: 8 },
      { sides: 10 },
      { sides: 12 },
      { sides: 20 }
    ],
  },
  methods: {
    rollDice: function(n, index) {
        Vue.set(this.rollResult, index, Math.ceil(Math.random() * n));
        console.log(this.rollResult);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(die, index) in dice" :key="die.name">
    <button class="primary" @click="rollDice(die.sides, index)">Roll {{ die.sides }}</button>
    <div>{{rollResult[index]}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much! <3 I don't have enough rep yet to upvote you, but I really appreciate your assistance!